# Remove GridView items one by one

Tags: android, gridview

[image]

I want to remove items from a gridView one by one. the problem is that are all removed once !

This is my code

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        boolean sw = false;
        while(!sw)
        {
            int i=0;

            if(!adapter.isEmpty())
            {
                adapter.removeItem(i);
                i+=1;
            } else sw = true;
        }
    }
}, 700);
```

in adapter I've created a remove function.. This it is

```
   public void removeItem(final int position)
    {
        data.remove(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Advices ?

Comment: I think you could look for animator

Comment: Because you remove all your items in the while-loop. You're not really delayed the removeItem() method call.

Comment: @Rami, yeah,, I thought that is the problem. but how to resolve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are running all the remove in one go, try with this

```
public void removeAllItem()
{
    Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() 
        {
            if(!adapter.isEmpty())
            {
                adapter.removeLastItem();
                removeAllItem();
            }
        } 
    }, 700);
}
```

and `removeLastItem()` is

```
public void removeLastItem()
{
    int lastIndex = data.size() - 1;
    data.remove(lastIndex);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Which will remove every item from the last index every 700 miliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Declare object in class level

```
boolean sw = false;
```

Change code like below

```
            while (!sw) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    int i = 0;

                    if (!adapter.isEmpty()) {
                        adapter.removeItem(i);
                        i += 1;
                    } else sw = true;

                }
            }, 700);
          }
```

Hope it will help you !!

Comment: if I declare it outside the Handler it has to be declared final. If it is declared final  I can't change it's value on else option...

Comment: pl define it in class level. post your code if not getting

Comment: I put it on class level, but the same problem, all are removed once and one one by one ! Thank you guys for helping me

Comment: I can't accept your answer because it is not working :)

Comment: Can you please post your whole code so I can help you more

Comment: Usually I also prefer iteration rather than recursion but if you call the remove function like this, it will start all the thread at the same time which will give the same result as hackingforgirls first solution.